# How to send email with javamail through gmail-account from inside openshift server?

Tags: email, gmail, jakarta-mail, openshift

I have a webapplication running at Openshift Free (redhat webhotel).
From this app I would like to send an email through my gmail account with the javax.mail-api.
When I try to run my code-attempts from my developer machine it works fine both with SSL and without SSL.
But when I run this from a JSP-page in my openshift server it does not work. I get this response back from gmail:

```
534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs0N
534-5.7.14 -wfEXm3iqKdenfgsums1_oLzBr3toWk44lKCVSpdKHkI2cJpo5ytmXFAU2LVn_4a3wrT-2
534-5.7.14 YUjbzlo4QJZRTxuWxujUOMJW8m5HMbUgHqZp0cBWjGZH-Nr5CZrHql_uZx_6IaEot3NJ-m
534-5.7.14 pBj85PCczPqx2q7NFQ6faPMgDRp7yEXlDAKOEZZ10gjxhQ3NLGFYV-_n9yS2ae49ZQOFHn
534-5.7.14 VTLSwBg> Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14 Learn more at
534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 g4sm1374527qas.22 - gsmtp
```

Below is code without SSL:

```
public static void sendGmail(String to, String subject, String text) throws AddressException, MessagingException
{
    final String SMTP_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com";
    final String SMTP_PORT = "587";
    final String GMAIL_USERNAME = "xxx@gmail.com";
    final String GMAIL_PASSWORD = "xxx";

    System.out.println("Process Started");

    Properties prop = System.getProperties();
    prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST);
    prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", GMAIL_USERNAME);
    prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.password", GMAIL_PASSWORD);
    prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_PORT);
    prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, new Authenticator()
    {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(GMAIL_USERNAME,
                    GMAIL_PASSWORD);
        }
    });
    session.setDebug(true);


    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(GMAIL_USERNAME));
    message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(to));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(text);
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(to));
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(SMTP_HOST, GMAIL_USERNAME, GMAIL_PASSWORD);
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
}
```

Below is code with SSL:

```
public static void sendGmail(String to, String subject, String text) throws AddressException, MessagingException
{
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    final String GMAIL_USERNAME = "xxx@gmail.com";
    final String GMAIL_PASSWORD = "xxx";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtps.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    session.setDebug(true);
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setText(text);
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
    msg.setHeader("X-Mailer", "smtpsend");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport)session.getTransport("smtps");

    try
    {
        t.connect(host, username, password);
        t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    } 
    finally
    {
        t.close();
    }
}
```

As you can see I run my attempts in debug mode for the session so below is the output from my attempts:

The debug output from my developer machine with SSL

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.2
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL true
220 mx.google.com ESMTP ny6sm229296lbb.2 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465

EHLO fredand
250-mx.google.com at your service, [90.230.21.163]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: check mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
bm9ycnVkZGVuLnZhZ2ZvcmVuaW5nQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
bm9ycnVkZGVuOTc=
235 2.7.0 Accepted
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<xxx@gmail.com>
250 2.1.0 OK ny6sm229296lbb.2 - gsmtp
RCPT TO:<xxx@hotmail.com>
250 2.1.5 OK ny6sm229296lbb.2 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   xxx@hotmail.com
DATA
354  Go ahead ny6sm229296lbb.2 - gsmtp
Date: Tue, 4 Nov 2014 15:23:48 +0100 (CET)
From: xxx@gmail.com
To: xxx@hotmail.com
Message-ID: <30266940.0.1415111029890.JavaMail.RPS@fredand>
Subject: Subject_Tue Nov 04 15:23:48 CET 2014
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-Mailer: smtpsend

text_Tue Nov 04 15:23:48 CET 2014
.
250 2.0.0 OK 1415111029 ny6sm229296lbb.2 - gsmtp
QUIT
221 2.0.0 closing connection ny6sm229296lbb.2 - gsmtp
```

The debug output from my openshift server with SSL

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.4
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL true
220 mx.google.com ESMTP 4sm1230842qax.48 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465

EHLO ex-std-node449.prod.rhcloud.com
250-mx.google.com at your service, [54.90.46.53]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: check mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
bm9ycnVkZGVuLnZhZ2ZvcmVuaW5nQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
bm9ycnVkZGVuOTc=
534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsvV
534-5.7.14 5K74amuA1WqDS9CFS1UPmuS3XUVU7lq0Agwb5DPcG69Z5fkYe6RUZrzAKPDWy9tQzq2BDg
534-5.7.14 1AxC2MmT1D1UXOXLG8cZuf7yKxKEUtaLo79a-fROXRiwCvMaqdvYXhqiIslXDTWJQZVe5W
534-5.7.14 qYvj9_ov5cziZe3ao5usZ-o58tHCv48yzrRm5SppAESXnvmv35ZLy4U9qF14GLEXHT7Wzj
534-5.7.14 QuIfn6w> Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14 Learn more at
534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 4sm1230842qax.48 - gsmtp
```

The debug output from my developer machine without SSL

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.2
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 mx.google.com ESMTP x6sm542099lbj.40 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587

EHLO fredand
250-mx.google.com at your service, [90.230.21.163]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
EHLO fredand
250-mx.google.com at your service, [90.230.21.163]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: check mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
bm9ycnVkZGVuLnZhZ2ZvcmVuaW5nQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
bm9ycnVkZGVuOTc=
235 2.7.0 Accepted
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<xxx@gmail.com>
250 2.1.0 OK x6sm542099lbj.40 - gsmtp
RCPT TO:<xxx@hotmail.com>
250 2.1.5 OK x6sm542099lbj.40 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   xxx@hotmail.com
DATA
354  Go ahead x6sm542099lbj.40 - gsmtp
From: xxx@gmail.com
To: xxx@hotmail.com
Message-ID: <27966883.0.1415135485593.JavaMail.RPS@fredand>
Subject: Subject_Tue Nov 04 22:11:24 CET 2014
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

text_Tue Nov 04 22:11:24 CET 2014
.
250 2.0.0 OK 1415135486 x6sm542099lbj.40 - gsmtp
```

The debug output from my openshift server without SSL

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.4
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.4]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 mx.google.com ESMTP g4sm1374527qas.22 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587

EHLO ex-std-node449.prod.rhcloud.com
250-mx.google.com at your service, [54.90.46.53]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
EHLO ex-std-node449.prod.rhcloud.com
250-mx.google.com at your service, [54.90.46.53]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: check mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
bm9ycnVkZGVuLnZhZ2ZvcmVuaW5nQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
bm9ycnVkZGVuOTc=
534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs0N
534-5.7.14 -wfEXm3iqKdenfgsums1_oLzBr3toWk44lKCVSpdKHkI2cJpo5ytmXFAU2LVn_4a3wrT-2
534-5.7.14 YUjbzlo4QJZRTxuWxujUOMJW8m5HMbUgHqZp0cBWjGZH-Nr5CZrHql_uZx_6IaEot3NJ-m
534-5.7.14 pBj85PCczPqx2q7NFQ6faPMgDRp7yEXlDAKOEZZ10gjxhQ3NLGFYV-_n9yS2ae49ZQOFHn
534-5.7.14 VTLSwBg> Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14 Learn more at
534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 g4sm1374527qas.22 - gsmtp
```

Do you guys get any clue why this is not working from my openshift server?

Best regards
Fredrik

Comment: You're using a very old version of JavaMail.  Because of that, you just published your Gmail password to the world.  Change it immediately.

Comment: And just to confirm, you read the [referenced URL](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754) and tried everything it suggested, right?  I understand you can't login using a browser from your openshift server.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply! No I can not login using the my code that using javamail api. I got no browser to use at the server.

Comment: Btw where did I show the password? I thought it was encrypted above, beacuse I do not think you mean my "xxx"?

Comment: It's not encrypted, it's just base64 encoded.  Anyone can decode it.

Comment: Thanks Bill for your help! After a lot of struggling it seems like the error was that I had not turned on IMAP clients: https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?authuser=1&rd=1#ts=1665018,1665144

Comment: I'm not quite sure why it worked from your developer machine if you hadn't enabled IMAP for your account.

Comment: You sure got a point there!! Hmm! I can not explaine it! Very strange!

Comment: Using the SSL variant above worked fine for me, but note that if you have 2-step-verification (a.k.a. two factor authentication) enabled on your Gmail account then you may need to use an Application Password rather than your account password, otherwise you will see a "Password incorrect" message. See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all help.
It seems like I needed to activate the IMAP at my gmail account.
After that it worked fine.

Best regards
Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

I had some difficulties with gmail, so I shifted to SendGrid to integrate JavaMail into a web application deployed onto OPENSHIFT for a dummy project.
I used SendGrid Trial.

Some Changes --

```
           // The SendGrid SMTP server.
             String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "smtp.sendgrid.net";

              Properties   properties = new Properties();
              // Specify SMTP values.
              properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
              properties.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
              properties.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);
              properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

You have to these two --

```
final String sendGridUser ="NameUChoose"; // Use At SendGrid Registration
   final String sendGridPassword="*****" ; // Use At SendGrid Registration
```

The rest is pretty much the same as other JavaMail code.

You have to authenticate your credentials also, so --

```
           // Create the authenticator object.
              Authenticator authenticator = new SMTPAuthenticator();
```

Create a separate java class , like --

```
package com.rana;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;

public class SMTPAuthenticator   extends Authenticator
{
    final String sendGridUser ="NameUChoose";
    final String sendGridPassword="*******;
       public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
       {
            String username = sendGridUser;
            String password = sendGridPassword;

            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);   
       }


}
```